# Is there a glutDisplayFunc equivalent in GLFW3?

Tags: c, glut, glfw, glew

I'm developing an OpenGL application in C, and I'm using glew/glfw3, and in glut I'm used to registering a looping function with `glutDisplayFunc`. Is there any such function in glew/glfw3, or do I have to write the loop myself?

I'm mainly asking because I want to use glew/glfw3 properly, and I feel like if such a function existed, it should be used.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is no. Glfw is completely different than glut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own loop.  This might help [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Window).
It shows setting up event callbacks and a while loop using mostly glfw functions.